# Comma-separated list of dynamic column names

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I would like to create a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012 with a comma-separated input parameter that will define which columns are selected. I will need to perform a simple calculation on some columns such as a SUM or AVG.

Sample data in table:

```
Amount Cost   Year Author
15.00  11.00  2011 Lloyd Christmas
17.00  50.00  2009 Billy Madison
12.00  10.00  2010 Joe Dirt
```

I would execute the SP using syntax similar to this (can be dynamic if it makes the code easier):

```
exec StoredProc @CSV = 'Amount,Year'
```

What makes this difficult is that I need to do simple calculations on the columns selected.

```
Select SUM([Amount]), AVG([YEAR]) 
FROM TBL
```

Another example:

```
exec StoredProc @CSV = "Amount,Cost,Year"

Select SUM([Amount]),SUM(Cost),AVG([YEAR]) 
FROM TBL
```

Comment: How is SQL Server supposed to know whether you want a SUM or an AVG? What does AVG([Year]) mean?

Comment: It would have to be a case statement.  AVG(year) would take the average of the years.  This is a dummy code, my real problem is much more complex and I just thinking of random values with calculations.

Comment: So AVG(Year) for the above sample data would be 2010? Please don't dumb things down for us. We can handle complex, and it is better to solve a real representation of your problem as opposed to made-up stuff that doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: Yes, but don't worry too much about that specific example.  You can change it to SUM if you want.

Comment: The problem is that i'm trying to apply python logic to solve this issue.  The logic I came up with is to parse the comma separated parameter into an array, and then loop over each element of the array.  Within the for loop, you'd have a case statement for each type of column and it's corresponding calculation. You could then append the results into a string and create a dynamic stored proc.  I really don't know how to parase the commma separated values and loop over the elements in sql.  I asked this question opened ended to see if there was better logic that can be applied in sql.

Comment: The example is not dumbed down.  That was poor word choice by me.  It's the same logic but with fictitious data.

Comment: So better explain - in English, not python or other code - how you would make a decision about whether to apply SUM() or some other aggregate against a column (and also indicate if any of the calculations are NOT aggregates). Do you have a list of column names you know should be SUM()? Is this based on the data type, or the name pattern, or the order in the list, or...?

Comment: Yes, I would use a case statement to select the type of calculation.  If it's column "Year", then use Avg(Year).  If it's Column Amount, then use Sum(Amount).  There will only be 6 definitions for columns.

Comment: Talking about this actually made me realize a simple solution. I'm not sure if it's the best, but it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the word in the parameter splitted in rows you can use a recursive `CTE`

```
Declare @CSV NVarchar(255) = 'Amount,Cost,Year'

;WITH Splitter AS (
  SELECT @CSV String
       , WordCounter = 0
       , NWordStart = 1
       , NWordEnd = CHARINDEX(',', @CSV)
       , Word = CAST('' AS NVarchar(255))
       , WordNumber = LEN(@CSV) - LEN(REPLACE(@CSV, ',', '')) + 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT s.String
       , WordCounter = s.WordCounter + 1
       , NWordStart = s.NWordEnd + 1
       , NWordEnd = COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', s.String, NWordEnd + 1), 0)
                           , LEN(s.String) + 1)
       , Word = Cast(SUBSTRING(String, s.NWordStart, s.NWordEnd - s.NWordStart) 
                  AS NVarchar(255))
       , WordNumber = s.WordNumber
  FROM   Splitter s
  WHERE  s.WordCounter + 1 <= s.WordNumber
)
SELECT Word
FROM   Splitter
WHERE  WordCounter > 0
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/18322)</kbd>

putting the results of that in a temporary table or a table variable you can than use them to create a dynamic query.

The `WHERE` condition in the main query remove the first result because, to simplify the `SUBSTRING`, the values are mixed:

- `NWordStart` and `NWordEnd` are the position of the start and the end for the next word
- `WordCounter` and `Word` the other fields are current, so the zeroth word is empty
- `WordNumber` is a constant to stop the recursion